# Android ListView with Image, TextView, Edittext, CheckBox

Tags: android

[image]

I want to design a ListView with Image, TextView, Edittext, CheckBox.

When user Checks the CheckBox of each list item and submit the Form, the selected ListItems and their EditText values should be captured.

I was trying to BaseAdapter but I was failed to get the correct checked values and edited text values from the ListView

Please guide me for achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I design a table layout with ImageView, TextView, EditText and CheckBox, And use a scroll view to scroll like a ListView

Answer (score 0):

maybe you try to ArrayAdapter for your app

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a custom ArrayAdapter wich uses your own custom xml layout.

Then you set your listView/listActivity to use this adapter.

Check out this [great tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive) by Lars Vogel.

Answer (score 0):

To get the values from CheckBox and EditText:

```
boolean state = checkBox.isChecked();
String text=myField.getText().toString();
```

Anyway, in the end you will end up with a custom adapter.
Check [Building a Custom Fancy ListView in Android](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/building-a-custom-fancy-listview-in-android/) about how to do it.